# Distance between two probability distributions

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

Are there any common ways to define a distance between two probablity distribution functions (i.e. how similar two distributions are)?

I am interested in the specific case where the random variable is discrete and can only take a finite number of values.

Comment: A simple [search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=distance+distributions) on this site gives you lots of related questions.

Answer (score 1):

The Kullback-Leibler divergence (i.e. relative entropy) does exactly that, as long as the two distributions have the same support.